# MATLAB two different arrays for the same variable

Tags: arrays, matlab

So, I got a strange problem.
Below is my code, it is a simple Euler method for integrating a Linear system of ODE's.

```
function [V, h, n, b, z] = hodgkin_huxley_CA1(t, Iapp, t_app)

%function based on the CA1 pyramidal neuron model: 

h = zeros(length(t));
n = zeros(length(t));
b = zeros(length(t));
z = zeros(length(t));
V = zeros(length(t));

% Initial conditions
h(1) = 0.9771;
n(1) = 0.0259;
b(1) = 0.1787;
z(1) = 8.0222e-04;
V(1) = -71.2856;

% Euler method
delta_t = t(2) - t(1);
for i=1:(length(t)-1)
    h(i+1) = h(i) + delta_t*feval(@h_prime,V(i),h(i));
    n(i+1) = n(i) + delta_t*feval(@n_prime,V(i),n(i));
    b(i+1) = b(i) + delta_t*feval(@b_prime,V(i),b(i));
    z(i+1) = z(i) + delta_t*feval(@z_prime,V(i),z(i));
    minf = m_inf(V(i));
    pinf = p_inf(V(i));
    ainf = a_inf(V(i));
    if (t(i) >= t_app(1) && t(i) <= t_app(2))
        I = Iapp;
    else I = 0;
    end;
    V(i+1) = V(i) + delta_t*feval(@V_prime,V(i),h(i),n(i),b(i),z(i),minf,pinf,ainf,I);
end;
```

So, this function returns me 5 arrays, V,h,n,b and z. The problem is that if I use V(1), V(2), V(3), ..., I get the expected result. But when I tell matlab to print the whole array, I receive all values as 0.
So, if I plot this array, I will get 2 curves: one that is the right one, and one that is zero. 
[image: as you can see from the graph]
Note that this also happens to all the other variables h,n,b and z.
Anyone knows what may be happening?

Comment: Are the outputs meant to be matrices or vectors?

Comment: they should be vectors

Comment: `numel` is a better option than `length`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outputs are meant to be vectors, however you are initializing them as square matrices.

You can simply replace:

```
h = zeros(length(t));
n = zeros(length(t));
b = zeros(length(t));
z = zeros(length(t));
V = zeros(length(t));
```

With

```
h = zeros(length(t),1);
n = zeros(length(t),1);
b = zeros(length(t),1);
z = zeros(length(t),1);
V = zeros(length(t),1);
```

The `zeros` function, with 1 input, creates a 2D square matrix of that dimension. With two or more inputs, it interprets the inputs as specification for all dimensions. For example:

```
>> x = zeros(3)
x =
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
>> x = zeros(3,1)
x =
     0
     0
     0
```